# Using a voltage ladder

Tags: voltage-divider

[image: schematic]

I have an old ATX power supply giving me two ground channels, a 5 V channel, and a 12 V channel.

The 5 V channel is used to trigger a series of relays, one at a time, using a rotary switch.

The relays are on an 8 relay low triggered optoisolated board. However optoisolation doesn't appear to make any difference-as I expected.

The relays connect the taps of a voltage array onto a shared bus. The voltage array is powered by the 12 V channel.

My expectation, and what I am trying to achieve, is that the voltage at each point will drop about 1.5 V measured on the bus. The last tap - nearest ground - should be about 1.5 V measured on the bus.

However, the 12 V channel referenced to the ground channel of the array sits at about 8.5 V and thus drops about 1 V per tap. When referenced against the other ground channel it is about 12 V but the last tap only goes down to about 4.5 V

The difference in voltage between the two ground channels is about 3.5 V. I assume that either I am doing something wrong - this is my hope - or this will never work because I have misunderstood something.

I have to check again, but removing the voltage ladder from the relay board results in the correct voltage reduction.

1. Is my theory - ie that I should be able to switch different voltages descending by about 1.5 volts from ~12v to ~1.5v - correct?
2. Is my circuit correct?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `difference in voltage between the two ground channels is about 3.5v` ... that makes no sense ... did you mix up pins on the connector?

Comment: `this will never work` ... what will never work? ... you did not say what you are trying to do

Comment: why would you need the relays?

Comment: Many PSU need a minimum load to regulate correctly. Try putting a *lamp* on the 12V channel to see if it stabilizes. Also the ATX supply outputs are *all* referenced to the same ground (i.e. all the black wires are tied together) so check your connections.

Comment: Lorenzo, there is a 10w 10ohm resister on one of the 5v wires. The 12v line has 8x470ohm on it so i don't think load is the problem. I was also of the opinion that all the black wires were tied together until I saw the difference in voltage. I will keep checking the connections.

Comment: Jsotota I need the relays because the rotary switch will not carry the possible amperage. This is driving a range of model rail locomotives. My power supply is rated at 2amps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly this is an attempt at a variable power supply (up to 12 V in 1.5 V steps).

It will probably not work as intended because the source impedance of your power supply will be very high (between 200 and 1000 Ohms about). If you connect a load to this with a resistance lower than about 1 kOhm, your results will be disappointing and the output voltage and power will be lower than expected. For high loads (e.g. 20 Ohm), the output voltage will collapse to a small fraction.

You could solve this, by taking the output of the voltage divider to a buffer (in the simplest case: a beefy MOSFET + heatsink), that you supply directly from the 12 V rail. This forms a linear regulator with a not ideal, but rather low output impedance. And you could replace the relays with much smaller switches because they wouldn't need to carry any current.

Comment: are you suggesting that if increase the resistors to 1kohm it will work

Comment: No. For this to "work" as is, the resistors in the ladder would have to be around 1 Ohm to give a usefully low output impedance. However, this will lead to an extremely high steady state output current of 10 A about, which will just flow to ground and heat (actually burn) the resistors. This is just not the way to build adjustable PSUs.

Answer (score 0):

The ATX power supply is connected using a heavy duty round 5 pin din plug. The male side of the connection was causing the 12v channel to drop 8.8v and one ground to rise 3.5v.

It seems that ATX power supplies - at least this one - starts doing weird things when there is a partial short. Like all ATX power supplies it shuts down on a full short.

With the plug removed, it correctly steps down in 1.5v increments between 12 and 1.5v.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple circuit that may meet your requirement.

[image]